# what is f""" """ and what is does?

Tags: python, syntax

I am a noob. I do not understand the syntax f""" """. Can someone explain what f""" """ does? What's the difference between f""" """ and f" ". Why f" " does not work in the following code?

> print(f"""{t1} and {t2}
> Agreed to have a battle;
> For {t1} said {t2}
> Had spoiled his nice new rattle.""")

Comment: It's a combination of [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python) and [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#one-line-docstrings). The docstring is used just so that the string can span multiple lines.

Comment: @rassar What does that have to do with docstrings?

Answer (score 1):

`""" """` is just a different way of defining a string, like `" "` and `' '`. It avoids the problem of having to escape " and ' characters if you want to use them in actual text (""" will be encountered quite rarely). As for "Why f" " does not work in the following code?" part of the question - it does work.

And f before string denotes an [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

""" is meant for multiple line text being turned into a variable.
Ex:

```py
v = """
line 1
Line 2
Line 3
"""
print(v)
```

This will exit with:

```py
line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

The "f" that comes before allows you to use the `{}` to use the variables inside the string.

```py
v = "hello"
print(f"{v} World!")
```

It does the same for """

This code should work, there is no reason for it not to with one "

Comment: Does Python really let you use `“` instead of `"`?? If not, your code examples are going to be problematic for people to copy and paste...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry I’m on an iPad, its not the best for coding

Comment: I've taken the liberty of fixing the quotes for you.